# Please help to solve the pde problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Prove that
$$u=e^{-4t}\cos\omega x$$ 
is  a solution of the one-dimensional wave equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=c^2\frac {\partial^2 u }{\partial x^2}.$$
I found 
$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial t}=-4e^{-4t}\cos\omega x$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=-\omega^2e^{-4t}\cos\omega x$$
but I can't equate the two. Please help to find a solution.

Comment: I feel like the 4 should be dependent on $\omega$ and $c$ somehow. Also, $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-4e^{-4t}\cos(\omega x)$.

Comment: so you are telling the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ i found is wrong

Comment: Yes. Note that $\cos(\omega x)$ does not depend on $t$ and when determining the partial derivative wrt $t$, $x$ is held constant.

Comment: Also, this seems more a heat equation than a wave equation.

Comment: @Daryl thanks for telling the mistake and you are right it was happened because of my carelessness

Answer (score 1):

I guess this means you have to *find* $\omega$ so that $u=e^{−4t}\cos\omega x$ satisfies $u_t=c^2u_{xx}$? By the way, this is called a *heat equation*, not a wave equation.

Comment: thanks timur for the info ,well how can i find $\omega$ can you please help?

Comment: @Biju: Maybe you want to compare the two sides of the equality you found?

Comment: equating the two the value of $\omega$ is 4 so we can tell the value of c is $2$ rgt

Comment: @Biju: You have to focus more.

Comment: i don't know man can you please help

Comment: w is +2 or -2  what's next